# JS mouseenter triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseenter

The problem is about event mouseenter which is triggered twice. 
The code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/xyrhacom/

HTML :

```
<div id="elt1" class="elt" val="text1">
    text1
    <div id="elt2" class="elt" val="text2">
        text2
    <div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".elt").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('val'));
    });
})
```

I understand the problem is the event is linked to the class attribute so it is triggered for each class, but I need to find a way to consider just the event triggered for the child.

In the example, when mouseover text2, it displays in the console 'text2 text1' but I want to find a way to only display 'text2' (keeping the same HTML code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **[stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**; Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".elt").mouseenter(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
        console.log($(this).attr('val'));
    });
})
```

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyrhacom/1/)

Comment: I don't know if things  were different when this question was answered but 'mouseenter' does NOT bubble at all as per MDN documentation in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Both #elt1 and #elt2 have your selector class (.elt )
use event.stopPropagation() to stop event from bubbling up in the DOM tree

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".elt").mouseenter(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log($(this).attr('val'));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to let the first child trigger the event, you can use a selector like:

```
$(".elt > .elt")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `elt2` is inside `elt1`, and the `mouseenter` event is bubbling up the DOM chain.  You need to stop the bubbling by using [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) to prevent your function from firing multiple times:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".elt").mouseenter(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log($(this).attr('val'));
    });
})
```

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/9e243sgL/

Cheers,
autoboxer